# How to ban IP addresses requesting specific directory using apache

Tags: apache, mod-security

Hello I'd like to **permenently ban** anything requesting the directory "/backups/" now how can I do that using a PHP script or mod_security?

I want to do this in a similar manner as iptables does this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this on my own.

create a script in /bin called "blockip" containing the following

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Blocking IP address $1"
iptables -A INPUT -s $1 -j DROP
```

then

```
chmod +x /bin/blockip
```

and now run

```
sudo visudo
```

add this:

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /your/script
```

make sure it is chmod 755

and add this code to index.php in the directory.

```
exec("sudo blockip ".escapeshellcmd($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```